# Резиновая высота картинки товара

Tags: css3, css, html, html5

Добрый вечер.

Кто-нибудь, подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить такую проблему: имеется фиксированная высота товара на сайте, но при его названии в одну строчку все отлично выводится с отступами, а как только вставляешь товар с длинным названием - все уходит вниз. Пример [здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/r4swvgkq/2/).

Как сделать, чтобы при длинном названии товара высота товара оставалась жесткой, а только уменьшалась основная картинка товара? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Alextrue](/users/23784/alextrue), вы сами себя ограничили, когда для родительского блока указали жёсткие размеры. По большому счету, стоило бы более глобально поменять верстку и стили, но если выкручиваться из того, что есть, то могу предложить ["поиграться" с помощью flexbox](http://jsfiddle.net/xj1psxso/). Основные изменения: добавили внутреннюю обёртку и такие стили для неё и дочерних элементов:

```
.product-table > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    height: 100%;
}
.product-table > div > * {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    align-self: stretch;
}
/* для h2 и блока с картинками */
.product-table h2 {
    flex: 1 0 25%;
    /* ... */
}
.product-table .product-table-img {
    flex: 1 0 25%;
}
```